# localstorage returning 'undefined' in react-redux app on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, jwt, local-storage

I'm using a react-redux application and trying to store my auth-token in localstorage.  As soon as my login api call completes, i put the auth-token in localStorage like so:

```
function loginSuccess(response) {
  const { accessToken, refreshToken} = response;
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
  localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken);
}
```

When I re-load the webpage, in my App.js when i try to retrieve accessToken and refreshToken, both return 'undefined'.  Why is this?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    ;
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
      authenticationActions.resetHeader();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to warn you that `localStorage` is insecure. Putting a refresh token (or even an access token) in `localStorage` is an incredibly bad idea. Also, you tagged the question with JWT, so I'm assuming you're saving those in localStorage as well, which is also very dangerous: https://medium.com/redteam/stealing-jwts-in-localstorage-via-xss-6048d91378a0

Comment: I would suspect that your issue is that the `response` object does not contain the values `accessToken` or `refreshToken`. If it is a `Response` object (i.e. from the Fetch API) then you need to wait for the `response.json()` Promise to resolve, and it will contain the data.

Comment: i put breakpoints where i was doing the localstorage.getItem('accessToken') and found that after waiting for sometime, the value returned.  It looks like its taking some time.  Is that common behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this happens if you are in incognito mode. Failing that... use the debugger and make sure that `accessToken` and `refreshToken` are not `undefined`. Failing that perhaps on refresh the `loginSuccess` function is running, again `debugger` is your friend here.

Comment: This is good advice, the issue is probably that he's trying to extract data from a `Response` object. OP needs to extract the data from the response, so maybe this resource could be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response